# views_query_alter add condition

Tags: 8

This looks appropriate for D7, but `add_where` doesn't exist in D8. What should I use?

```
/**
 * Filter out the current node from the view query
 */
if ($view->id() == 'videos') {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node) {
        $query->add_where(0, $node->ID(), 'nid', 'NOT IN');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You try code:

```
 use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
 use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
....

   /**
    * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
    */
    function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
     $query->addWhere(0, 'node__field_data.nid', [1,2,3], 'IN');
    }
```